# How to enable remote JMX on Kafka brokers (for JmxTool)?

Tags: apache-kafka, jmx

I enabled JMX on Kafka brokers by adding

```
KAFKA_JMX_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true
                -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
                -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
                -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<server_IP>
                -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
```

However, when I use `kafka.tools.JmxTool` to get the JMX metrics, it outputs Unix timestamps only. Why?

```
./bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.JmxTool \
  --object-name 'kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=AllTopicsMessagesInPerSec' \
  --jmx-url "service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://<server_IP>:9111/jmxrmi"
```

How can I have it print out the metrics?

Comment: editing the sh files is not a good idea. why is everyone recommending it?

Answer (score 25):

Edit bin/kafka-run-class.sh and set KAFKA_JMX_OPTS variable

```
KAFKA_JMX_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=your.kafka.broker.hostname -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
```

Update bin/kafka-server-start.sh add the below line

```
export JMX_PORT=PORT
```

Comment: Only `export JMX_PORT=PORT` before start of Kafka service is enough to enable JMX on my mac. I tested this with jconsole. And if you want to connect producer and consumer, set/export different jmx port before start of each.

Comment: is it necessary to restart kafka ?

Comment: @DivyanshuJimmy yeap :)

Comment: You can export outside of the script. Don't modify it

Answer (score 10):

If you're running via systemd:

1. edit **/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/kafka.service**
2. in the "[service]" section add a line:

   - *Environment=JMX_PORT=9989*
3. reload: `systemctl daemon-reload`
4. restart: `systemctl restart kafka`
5. enjoy the beans: `echo 'beans' | java -jar jmxterm-1.0-alpha-4-uber.jar -l localhost:9989 -n 2>&1`

Answer (score 9):

You must set 'JMX_PORT' variable, or add the following line to bin/kafka-server-start.sh.

```
export JMX_PORT=${JMX_PORT:-9999}
```

then you will be able to connect to Kafka JMX metrics. I use jconsole tool and 'localhost:9999' address.

Answer (score 9):

Setting `JMX_PORT` inside `bin/kafka-run-class.sh` will clash with Zookeeper, if you are running Zookeeper on the same node.
Best is to set `JMX` port individually inside corresponding `server-start` scripts:

1. Insert line `“export JMX_PORT=${JMX_PORT:-9998}”` before last line in `$KAFKA_HOME/bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh` file.
2. Restart the Zookeeper server.
3. Repeat steps 1 and 2 for all zookeeper nodes in the cluster.
4. Insert line `“export JMX_PORT=${JMX_PORT:-9999}”` before last line in `$KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-server-start.sh` file.
5. Restart the Kafka Broker.
6. Repeat steps 4 and 5 for all brokers in the cluster.

Comment: This answer is perfectly worked for my problem. I'm using kafka_2.11-2.0.0  & zookeeper-3.4.12 together as 3 node cluster. This solution worked for Kafka-Manager's JMX based metrics display charts as well as kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper & Kafka Console Producer (kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list ) & Console Consumer (kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server) & kafka-topics.sh --describe. Zookeeper & Kafka both are working on different JMX ports. Zookeeper working on port 9998 and Kafka & Kafka-Manager working on port 9999. Thank you @Rahul Singhai

Comment: Every Kafka Broker using same JMX port?

Comment: No, if running multiple Kafka Brokers or ZKs on same node, then you need to specify different JMX ports for each of them.

Comment: I suggest not modifying the shell scripts because those shouldn't be kept across server upgrades

Answer (score 4):

This is Kafka 2.3.0.

### Using jconsole For Available MBeans

You should use `jconsole` first to know the names of the MBeans available.

The proper name of the MBean you wanted to query metrics of is `kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec` (the `AllTopics` prefix was used in older verions). Thanks [AndyTheEntity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39995297/1305344).

[image: jconsole]

### Enabling Remote JMX (with no authentication or SSL)

As described in [Monitoring and Management Using JMX Technology](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html) you should set certain system properties when you start the Java VM of a Kafka broker.

Kafka's `bin/kafka-run-class.sh` shell script makes the configuration painless as it does the basics for you and sets `KAFKA_JMX_OPTS`.

```
# JMX settings
if [ -z "$KAFKA_JMX_OPTS" ]; then
  KAFKA_JMX_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false "
fi
```

For remote JMX you should set `com.sun.management.jmxremote.port` that Kafka's `bin/kafka-run-class.sh` shell script sets using `JMX_PORT` environment variable.

```
# JMX port to use
if [  $JMX_PORT ]; then
  KAFKA_JMX_OPTS="$KAFKA_JMX_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=$JMX_PORT "
fi
```

With that, enabling remote JMX is as simple as the following command:

```
JMX_PORT=9999 ./bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
```

### Using JmxTool

With the above, run the JmxTool:

```
$ ./bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.JmxTool \
  --object-name 'kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec'
Trying to connect to JMX url: service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://:9999/jmxrmi.
"time","kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec:Count","kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec:EventType","kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec:FifteenMinuteRate","kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec:FiveMinuteRate","kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec:MeanRate","kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec:OneMinuteRate","kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec:RateUnit"
1567586728595,0,messages,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,SECONDS
1567586730597,0,messages,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,SECONDS
...
```

You could use `--one-time` option to print the JMX metrics just once.

```
$ ./bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.JmxTool \
    --object-name 'kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec' \
    --one-time true
Trying to connect to JMX url: service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://:9999/jmxrmi.
"time","kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec:Count","kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec:EventType","kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec:FifteenMinuteRate","kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec:FiveMinuteRate","kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec:MeanRate","kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec:OneMinuteRate","kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec:RateUnit"
1567586898459,0,messages,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,SECONDS
```

Answer (score 2):

```
vim kafka_2.11-0.10.1.1/bin/kafka-run-class.sh
```

and then add the first two lines and comment as I have done for other lines, (Note : after doing this Kafka scripts cannot be used for client operations for listing topics.. for your client operations you need to use a separate scripts , download again in different locations and use)

```
export JMX_PORT=9096
KAFKA_JMX_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<ipaddress> -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=$JMX_PORT -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=$JMX_PORT"



# JMX settings
#if [ -z "$KAFKA_JMX_OPTS" ]; then
# KAFKA_JMX_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false "

#fi

# JMX port to use
#if [  $JMX_PORT ]; then
#  KAFKA_JMX_OPTS="$KAFKA_JMX_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=$JMX_PORT "
#fi
```

Comment: Right idea, wrong implementation. You're right that you may need to set other JMX JVM args, but you should set those variables before invoking the script, don't modify the script itself. You're setting yourself up for a maintenance headache.

Answer (score 1):

This is standard Kafka start procedure:

```sh
bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
```

This is Kafka start procedure with **JMX**:

```sh
JMX_PORT=8004 bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec`

The `AllTopics` prefix was used in older verions. You can specify topic using `kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec,topic=<topic-name>`

src: http://grokbase.com/t/kafka/users/164ksnhff0/enable-jmx-on-kafka-brokers

Answer (score 0):

Kafka has provided all you need. When your start your server, activate the KAFKA_JMX_OPTS arg by using these command:

`$KAFKA_JMX_OPTS JMX_PORT=[your_port_number] ./kafka-server-start.sh -daemon ../config/server.properties`

Using those command, you activated JMX Remote and related port. Then you can connect your JConsole or another monitoring tools.

Answer (score 0):

Just before calling kafka-server-start.sh add following exports. It worked like a charm for my case. You can set desired port for JMX_PORT and you should set broker for $BROKER_IP part.

```
   export JMX_PORT=9900
   export KAFKA_JMX_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=$BROKER_IP -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
```

Answer (score 0):

I just want to share my experience related to JMX_PORT

I'm using windows OS. and I configure my JMX_PORT under \bin\windows\kafka-run-class.bat.

Since I'm using zookeeper and kafka server on the same node, and I start the zookeeper first (successfully start). And then I start the kafka server (failed start). And the reason it failed is because the script to run both zookeeper and kafka server refer to the same script that set the JMX_PORT(kafka-run-class.bat).

What I do is modify the **kafka-run-class.bat**
by adding parameter checking to decide the JMX_PORT to be use by zookeeper and kafka server start script.

```
IF %1 == kafka.Kafka (
    rem using port 8005 for the Kafka server 
    set JMX_PORT=8005
)
IF %1 == org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain (
    rem using port 8004 for the ZooKeeper
    set JMX_PORT=8004
)
```