# How to monitor JMX metrics of Kafka broker on command line?

Tags: apache-kafka, jmx

A Kafka cluster can be monitored in granular detail via the JMX metrics it exposes. Usually an external GUI or application like `jconsole` needs to be hooked up to a broker's exposed `JMX_PORT` in order to view these metrics.

Is there a way that I can view a broker's JMX metrics in an SSH session, via `STDOUT`?
Is there a native Kafka command that I can run to view these metrics?

Comment: This is not specific to Kafka, but here is a prior answer with a lot of options for command line JMX utilities.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751130/calling-jmx-mbean-method-from-a-shell-script

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Download the jar located here:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/cyclops-group/files/jmxterm/1.0-alpha-4/

On the machine, then run:

`wget https://sourceforge.net/projects/cyclops-group/files/jmxterm/1.0-alpha-4/ -o jmxterm.jar`

`java -jar jmxterm.jar`

`>open localhost:$jmx_port`

Help will give you what you need after that :)

Save this jar somewhere useful, I use it nearly every day.

Comment: This is giving "#RuntimeIOException: Runtime IO exception: Service URL must start with service:jmx:" though I am not using the same jar but "jmxterm-1.0.2-uber.jar"

Answer (score 20):

Use `kafka.tools.JmxTool`.

Assuming you have [enabled JMX on your broker](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36708384/1305344) on the default port of 9999, you can simply run this example command to print out jmx metrics for BrokerTopics via STDOUT

```
$ ./bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.JmxTool \
  --object-name kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec
Trying to connect to JMX url: service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://:9999/jmxrmi.
"time","kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec:Count","kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec:EventType","kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec:FifteenMinuteRate","kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec:FiveMinuteRate","kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec:MeanRate","kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec:OneMinuteRate","kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec:RateUnit"
1567587563143,0,messages,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,SECONDS
1567587565148,0,messages,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,SECONDS
1567587567150,0,messages,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,SECONDS
...
```

`JmxTool` prints out JMX metrics every `--reporting-interval` option.

> **--reporting-interval <Integer: ms>**
>
> Interval (in millis) with which to poll jmx stats
>
> Default: `2000` (2 seconds)
>
> Value of `-1` is equivalent to `--one-time true`