# How to monitor apache kafka using nagios?

Tags: apache-kafka, monitoring, metrics, nagios

Is there a way to monitor my kafka cluster using nagios? any working plugin, api or whatever to check: broker status, partition status, memory status, current offset and all valuable metrics from my cluster?

Answer (score 3):

We are using Nagios to monitor Kafka JMX metrics (we use JMXeval, but you can use any of your favorite JMX monitoring script for Nagios) where we can find many useful metrics like memory, lag, number of offline partition, and so on.

I can highly recommend you to read this article about Kafka monitoring, where you can find many useful tips what you can monitor - https://blog.serverdensity.com/how-to-monitor-kafka/

Because JMX is by default disabled, you need enable it first. You can follow instruction on [Enable JMX on Kafka Brokers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36708384/enable-jmx-on-kafka-brokers)