# Fetching kafka mbeans using jmx with java

Tags: java, apache-kafka, jmx, monitor

I'm trying to get mbeans of Kafka using Java code ( consumer or producer ) like they appear in jconsole
In jconsole I can see the name of the mbean ( like : `objetName:kafka.consumer:type=consumer-fetch-manager-metrics,client-id=consumer-1`)

so here is my code :

```
JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:9998/jmxrmi");
```

where port is like in the  config file ( `server.properties`)  that I set (**I set port in Kafka config file ( SET JMX_PORT=9098** )
, I also tried to use my Kafka port  ( 9092) but than I get address in use -

```
 bean=new ObjectName("kafka.consumer:type=consumer-coordinator-metrics,client-id=consumer-1");
MBeanInfo info= connection.getMBeanInfo(bean);
```

I get InstanceNotFoundException

when I  use this  code :

```
domains=connection.getDomains();
```

I get all the domains except kafka.consumer ( i.e `java.nio,java.util.logging , java.lang` .. etc )
but not the `kafka.server` even though I can see the `kafka.consumer` mbeans in Jconsole ..

but, I don't know how to access the JMXServiceURL:
I tried to give the folloiwing : new

I also tries this :

```
MBeanServer mbs = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
```

but after I get the server bean , I cannot see Kafka mbeans (just other custom mbeans that i created or others but not Kafka mbeans )

I think that Kafka exposes the port to jconsole in some port which I cannot figure it

Any ideas ?

Comment: Your code says port 9998, but you used 9098 in the bat file? (you shouldn't edit the bat file, anyway, and JMX isn't defined in server.properties )

Comment: The problem is that I don't know what is the connection string :i.e :JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:9998/jmxrmi"); what is th  port that  the kafka server expose the mbeans ?

Comment: By default, it doesn't. That's why you set the variable before starting the broker in the terminal, but if you want to connect to it, then use the same port

Comment: Did you see this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36708384/how-to-enable-remote-jmx-on-kafka-brokers-for-jmxtool